# Geostationary orbit with pyephem?

Tags: astronomy, pyephem, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to create a geostationary orbit in pyephem (`_n = 1.0` revolutions per day).  I would like to verify that it is geostationary by placing an observer directly below the satellite and verifying that alt='90.0' and az=0.  For my test I am placing the observer on the equator at 100 deg W longitude.  Here is my code:

```
import ephem

sat = ephem.EarthSatellite()
sat._n = 1.0
sat._e = 0.0
sat._inc = 0.0
sat._raan = '-100.0'
sat._ap = 0.0
sat._M = 0.0

obs = ephem.Observer()
obs.lat = 0.0
obs.lon = '-100.0'
obs.date = '2014/10/16 00:00:00'

sat.compute(obs)
print "obs position: lat=%s lon=%s date=%s" % \
    (obs.lat, obs.lon, obs.date)
print "sat orbit: n=%s e=%s inc=%s raan=%s ap=%s M=%s" % \
    (sat._n, sat._e, sat._inc, sat._raan, sat._ap, sat._M)
print "sat position: alt=%s az=%s ra=%s dec=%s sublat=%s sublong=%s" % \
    (sat.alt, sat.az, sat.ra, sat.dec, sat.sublat.norm, sat.sublong.norm)
```

and the output:

```
> obs position: lat=0:00:00.0 lon=-100:00:00.0 date=2014/10/16 00:00:00
> sat orbit: n=1.0 e=0.0 inc=0:00:00.0 raan=-1:44:43.2 ap=0:00:00.0 M=0:00:00.0
> sat position: alt=-90:00:00.0 az=0:00:00.0 ra=6:57:44.67 dec=0:00:00.0 sublat=1389660529:33:00.8 sublong=335:33:55.8
```

I find that changing the observer longitude does not change the output.  I expect that `sat._raan` sets the overhead position (`sat.sublong`) of the satellite, but this also has no affect on the output.  I consistently get alt=-90:00:00.0 az=0:00:00.0. (Towards center of Earth) and sublat, sublong don't make any sense.

---

## Update

The reason for the strange, unchanging output of `sublat=1389660529:33:00.8` is due to the `sat._epoch` being '1899/12/31 12:00:00' by default, along with this [issue](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/56).  Setting `sat._epoch = obs.date` works around this, but I am still not sure how to achieve the goal of defining a geostationary orbit whose sky position is fixed above a chosen Earth coordinate.

Comment: By the way, in the next version of PyEphem there will be protection for users who try using TLE elements that are far too old, to prevent these outlandish return values that you saw: https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/56

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about astronomy and not really programming related.